# C++ method in QML never called, still works

Tags: c++, qml, qproperty

I am new to QML and saw [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) code. It works fine, but what confuses me is that the method setUsername was never called in the qml file. So my question is how this Q_PROPERTY works. Does anyone have a good explaination for this?

Comment: I think that when you write `Q_PROPERTY(QString userName READ userName WRITE setUserName NOTIFY userNameChanged)` you tell QT to handle events  related to field `userName` wich call automaticaly `setUserName` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q_PROPERTY(QString userName READ userName WRITE setUserName NOTIFY userNameChanged)
This is used to make use of property like qml.
So you can use  like every variable as like a qml variable.
QML will read value of property of  with c++ function userName () with keyword . And write to  with function setUserName().
Then the modification is notify by signal userNameChanged.